# rake task undefined method create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So my other rake task that has the create options work fine.

However this one

```
   task test: :environment do
       ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE Tables RESTART IDENTITY")
       gzipped = open('csv url')
       csv_text = Zlib::GzipReader.new(gzipped).read
       csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers=>true)
       csv.each do |row|
          Table.create(db information])
       end
     end
```

Now for some reason this is failing o the create action (which is the exact same as my other create actions) I don;t have a controller for these. My model is empty but exists with the naming convention there.

Any ideas?

The error is this

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `create' for Table:Module
```

(Table is used as a replacement before i get called out for bad practise)

Comment: What is the actual name for that class? Is it the same as your app name? Rails gives you a hint in form of `Table:Module`. It should be a class, not a module. Which means that there's a module with this name which shadows your class.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I don't follow, Its already being used elsewhere? I'm sure i've not got it used elsewhere?

Comment: No, you're not sure. Because evidently you _are_ using it elsewhere.

Comment: So what am i looking for? Table? Tables? or what?

Comment: You seem to expect `Table` to be a Model (a class inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base`) but it is evidently not. Show in your app where you are defining `Table`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't really know the wider problem. But in your code I see a missing `[` on this line: `Table.create(db information])`

That might have something to do with it?